# Issue with Enabling/Disabling Select Boxes in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two select groups where I am trying to connect the second to the first, based on the first selection, to provide the appropriate color options for the user.

On page load, the correct list of color options displays in second select box based on selection in first box ('Select Theme'). Then if you change back to a different design, the right color options load in second select group.  But then if you change back again, all of the color options are deselected.  I've stared at this all day and can't identify the issue.

Here is HTML

```js
//On selection of the design, sets appropriate color based on the design selected
$('#design').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'js puns') {
    $('.js').prop('disabled', true);
    $('.js_puns').prop('disabled', false);
  } else if ($(this).val() == 'heart js') {
    $('.js_puns').prop('disabled', true);
    $('js').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('js').prop('disabled', false);
    $('js_puns').prop('disabled', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label for="design">Design:</label>
  <select id="design" name="user_design">
                <option>Select Theme</option>
                <option value="js puns">Theme - JS Puns</option>
                <option value="heart js">Theme - I &#9829; JS</option>
              </select>
</div>

<div id="colors-js-puns" class="">
  <label for="color">Color:</label>
  <select id="color">
                <option>Select Color</option>
                <option value="cornflowerblue" class="js_puns">Cornflower Blue (JS Puns shirt only)</option>
                <option value="darkslategrey" class="js_puns">Dark Slate Grey (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
                <option value="gold" class="js_puns">Gold (JS Puns shirt only)</option> 
                <option value="tomato" class="js">Tomato (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option>
                <option value="steelblue" class="js">Steel Blue (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
                <option value="dimgrey" class="js">Dim Grey (I &#9829; JS shirt only)</option> 
              </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing the period in `$('js')` in a few places. Should be `$('.js')`. Same for `$('js_puns')`. Should be `$('.js_puns')`

Comment: haha...WOW --sometimes it really is that easy.  blindness from staring at code is a real thing.  thank you!!